# ImageView of a item in the list shuffled when scrolling

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a list,When user clicks an item in that list three buttons will be showed under that item (namely Yes,No and Maybe) so user may select any one of the buttons and that response(as 1,2,3 for yes,no,maybe) will be saved.In  adapter's getView just we retrieve that response and showing imageView on all list item's row

setting image in ArrayAdapter's getView

```
EventUserRelationMO eventUserRelationMO1 =new EventUserRelationMO();
                    eventId1 = eventUserRelationMO1.getEventId();
                    if (eventId1 == eventIdPosition) {
                        long eventUserId = eventUserRelationMO1.getEventUserId();

                        int isAttending = eventUserRelationMO1.getIsAttending();
                        if (isAttending == 1) {
                            holder.no.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            holder.maybe.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        } else if (isAttending == 2) {
                            holder.yes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            holder.maybe.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        } else if (isAttending == 3) {
                            holder.yes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            holder.no.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        } else {
                            holder.yes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            holder.no.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            holder.maybe.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }

                    }
```

this is perfectly works but when i have more number of items in the list image is not visible for corresponding item/shuffled while scrolling

```
private class UserOccasions extends ArrayAdapter<EventMO> {
        private ArrayList<EventMO> eventMOs;
        LayoutInflater mInflater;

        UserOccasions(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                      ArrayList<EventMO> eventMOs) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, eventMOs);
            this.eventMOs = new ArrayList<EventMO>();
            this.eventMOs.addAll(eventMOs);
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        }

        public class ViewHolder {
            TextView eventNameTxtV;
            TextView eventPlaceTxtV;
            TextView sendByNameTxtv;
            ImageView yes;
            ImageView no;
            ImageView maybe;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return eventMOs.size();
        }

        /*@Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }*/

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        // show list values name and mobile number in contact page
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            final EventMO eventMO = eventMOs.get(position);
            if (null == convertView) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.invitation, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.eventNameTxtV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.invitationTitle);
                holder.eventPlaceTxtV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.invitationCheckBox);
                holder.sendByNameTxtv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sendByName);
                holder.yes = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.yes);
                holder.no = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.no);
                holder.maybe = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.maybe);

                eventUserRelationMOs = eventMO.getEventUserRelationBOs();
                sendUserMO = eventMO.getUserBO();
                eventIdPosition = eventMO.getEventId();


                for (EventUserRelationMO eventUserRelationMO1 : eventUserRelationMOs) {
                    eventId1 = eventUserRelationMO1.getEventId();
                    if (eventId1 == eventIdPosition) {
                        long eventUserId = eventUserRelationMO1.getEventUserId();

                        int isAttending = eventUserRelationMO1.getIsAttending();
                        if (isAttending == 1) {
                            holder.no.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            holder.maybe.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        } else if (isAttending == 2) {
                            holder.yes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            holder.maybe.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        } else if (isAttending == 3) {
                            holder.yes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            holder.no.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        } else {
                            holder.yes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            holder.no.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            holder.maybe.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }

                    }
                }
                convertView.setTag(holder);

            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.yes.setTag(eventMOs.get(position));
            holder.no.setTag(eventMOs.get(position));
            holder.maybe.setTag(eventMOs.get(position));

                       holder.eventNameTxtV.setText(eventMOs.get(position).getText());
            holder.eventPlaceTxtV.setText(eventMOs.get(position).getPlace());
            holder.sendByNameTxtv.setText(sendUserMO.getUserName());

                       View v = convertView.findViewById(R.id.invitation_single);

            v.getRootView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   Intent occasionAct = new Intent(InvitationFragment.this.getActivity(), InvitationActivity.class);
                    occasionAct.putExtra("eventMO", eventMO);
                    occasionAct.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(occasionAct);

                }

            });

            return convertView;

        }
```

this is my full adapter code any one help me to maintain corresponding imageView for each item in the list when scrolling

Answer (score 0):

ListView works by recycling the views.To know more on how it works you can have a look at this (http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/).

The problem with the code is that the image is being set only once when convertView is null. When you scroll the list, the list view passes a recycled row into the getView function (this is when the convertView will not be null). In this case you are not setting the ImageView.

I have modified the code, this should work

```
// show list values name and mobile number in contact page
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        final EventMO eventMO = eventMOs.get(position);
        if (null == convertView) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.invitation, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.eventNameTxtV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.invitationTitle);
            holder.eventPlaceTxtV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.invitationCheckBox);
            holder.sendByNameTxtv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sendByName);
            holder.yes = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.yes);
            holder.no = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.no);
            holder.maybe = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.maybe);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        eventUserRelationMOs = eventMO.getEventUserRelationBOs();
        sendUserMO = eventMO.getUserBO();
        eventIdPosition = eventMO.getEventId();


         for (EventUserRelationMO eventUserRelationMO1 : eventUserRelationMOs) {
            eventId1 = eventUserRelationMO1.getEventId();
            if (eventId1 == eventIdPosition) {
                long eventUserId = eventUserRelationMO1.getEventUserId();

                int isAttending = eventUserRelationMO1.getIsAttending();
                if (isAttending == 1) {
                    holder.no.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.maybe.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else if (isAttending == 2) {
                    holder.yes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.maybe.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else if (isAttending == 3) {
                    holder.yes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.no.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    holder.yes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.no.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.maybe.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

            }
        }

        holder.yes.setTag(eventMOs.get(position));
        holder.no.setTag(eventMOs.get(position));
        holder.maybe.setTag(eventMOs.get(position));

        holder.eventNameTxtV.setText(eventMOs.get(position).getText());
        holder.eventPlaceTxtV.setText(eventMOs.get(position).getPlace());
        holder.sendByNameTxtv.setText(sendUserMO.getUserName());

        View v = convertView.findViewById(R.id.invitation_single);

        v.getRootView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent occasionAct = new Intent(InvitationFragment.this.getActivity(), InvitationActivity.class);
                occasionAct.putExtra("eventMO", eventMO);
                occasionAct.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(occasionAct);

            }

        });

        return convertView;

    }
```

Comment: thank you for your response i have tried your code but when i set icon for the first item it sets the icon for 2 items -first one and seventh one.The icons also shuffled  while scrolling@ Anirudh R Kashyap